# Why won't my Composer package autoload?

Tags: php, composer-php

I've been testing getting my packages up to Packagist with a simple class I made. Whenever I require it in a different project, it says the class cannot be found. Is something wrong with my composer.json `autoload` block?

Here's my project repo **file structure**:

```
- src
    - prodikl
        - View.php
- .gitignore
- composer.json
```

And here's my **composer.json**:

```
{
  "name":"prodikl/simple-view",
  "description":"A simple to use, basic View object.",
  "require" : {
    "php" : ">=5.3.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"prodikl": "src/"}
  }
}
```

And finally, in my **View.php**:

```
<?php

namespace prodikl;

class View
{
    ...
}
```

But whenever I require it into a project and do `require "vendor/autoload.php"` and use `use prodikl\View;` it it keeps saying not found

Comment: What if you use `prodikl\\\` to indicate namespace?

Comment: i think that was part of it, yup!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to point your autoloader down one more directory:

```
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"prodikl": "src/prodikl/"}
  }
```

This means "classes that belong to the `\prodikl` namespace can be found in the `src/prodikl/` directory."

You might need trailing backslashes on the namespace name too, not sure how picky Composer is about it:

```
"psr-4": {"prodikl\\": "src/prodikl/"}
```

Comment: that was exactly it! i tried a few variations of that path but this is the correct one. thanks!